# Bind observerbaleCollection to wpf combo box

Tags: wpf, wcf, data-binding, observablecollection

I'm having Class call Apps. It has `Observable collection` called **AvailableTypes**. I want to bind this AvailableTypes observable collection to the wpf `ComboBox`. When form is loaded these AppId should loaded into comboBox.. Would you give me a solution to this one?

```
class Apps: INotifyPropertyChanged{

    ServiceReference1.AssetManagerServiceClient client;
    ObservableCollection<string> availableType;
    public ObservableCollection<string> AvailableTypes
    {
        get
        {
            if (availableType == null)
            {
                availableType = new ObservableCollection<string>();

            }
            client = new ServiceReference1.AssetManagerServiceClient();
            List<string> AssestList = client.GetAppIds().ToList<string>();

            foreach (string appid in AssestList)
            {
                availableType.Add(appid);
            }
            return availableType;

        }
        set
        {
            availableType = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("AvailableTypes");

        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your xaml code, this is a simple example of how you can bind to your combobox.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource={Binding Path=AvailableTypes} />
```

You will also need to load your viewmodel into the DataContext of your window too.

```
var window = new MainWindow
{
    DataContext = new Apps()
};
window.Show();
```

If you want open the window on App startup, you can do this instead

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);


        var window = new MainWindow
        {
            DataContext = new Apps()
        };

        window.Show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't overload property getters/setters. Make it simplier.

I recommend to use auto properties and [NotifyPropertyWeaver](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bd351303-db8c-4771-9b22-5e51524fccd3) or use [PostSharp](http://www.richard-banks.org/2009/02/aspect-oriented-programming.html) post build compile-time injected instuctions to support INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

This makes your view model more readable and easy to manage/understand.

In your form 'Loaded' event or 'NavigatedTo' in SL you can start loading your data from anywhere you want and set corresponding properties after loading completed (in callbacks/events handlers, don't forget about using UI dispatcher while updating binded properties)